# Return Excel downloadable file from Spring

Tags: java, spring, excel, spring-mvc

So I have a Spring controller, and I'd like to create an Excel file and return it so that it is downloaded by the browser.

I'm using JEXcelApi.

This is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/excel/cols/{colString}/rows/{rowString}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> exportExcel(HttpServletResponse response,
    @PathVariable List<String> colString,
    @PathVariable List<String> rowString) throws JSONException, IOException, WriteException {
    WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("exported.xls"));
    WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Exported",0);
    String[] cols = colString.get(0).split(",");
    String[] rows = rowString.get(0).split(","); 
    for(int i = 0; i < cols.length;i++){
        Label label = new Label(i,0, cols[i]);
        sheet.addCell(label);
    }
    int excelCol = 0;
    int excelRow = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows.length;i++){
        Label label = new Label(excelCol,excelRow, rows[i]);
        sheet.addCell(label);
        excelCol++;
        if((i+1) % cols.length == 0){
            excelCol = 0;
            excelRow++;
        }
    }
    workbook.write();
    workbook.close();
    return null;
}
```

How do I do that? I suspect there's some content header I can set. I know one method is to use Spring's Abstract Excel view class, but is there a simpler method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Disposition` header.

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=" + yourFileName);
```

and write your bytes directly to the response `OutputStream`.

```
File xls = new File("exported.xls"); // or whatever your file is
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(xls);
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

byte[] buffer= new byte[8192]; // use bigger if you want
int length = 0;

while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
     out.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
in.close();
out.close();
```

---

The above is relatively old. You can construct a `ResponseEntity` with [`FileSystemResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html) now. A [`ResourceHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/ResourceHttpMessageConverter.html) will then copy the bytes, as I have suggested above, for you. Spring MVC makes it simpler for you rather than having you interact with interfaces from the Servlet specification.

Comment: ah so what then gets returned?

Comment: ah, is there any chance you could write the writing to stream code?

Comment: so I tried that - but nothing is downloading, instead what's happening is something is console logging out - this is coming from the success function from my client

Comment: oh one more question - is there a way to dynamically alter the buffer array - because if the file is very big, this method won't work right?