# Downloading Excel using POST Rest Service

Tags: excel, rest, post

I'm using REST web services provided by Spring Framework.
I need to download an excel sheet but i also need to donwload the sheet on basis of some selected parameters. I'm sending a request class object as the Body to a POST Rest call(@RequestBody)

I could not download the excel using a POST Method. Please help me to achieve this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/export", method = RequestMethod.POST,, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void searchResultToExcel(@RequestBody SearchRequest searchRequest, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
```

This is my method signature

Comment: Why are you using POST? Why not use a GET with the search parameters in the query string?

Comment: the search parameters is a type of an object :(

Comment: Are you saying that you are not in control of the frontend app?

Comment: Quick silly question. Would you normally use a fetch/get method if you weren't passing parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I've found this thread [Return Excel downloadable file from Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648823/return-excel-downloadable-file-from-spring) that may be useful.

I also think that content-type you're forcing (produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) might be in the way, at least as far as I could understand the question. I think you should be forcing for an EXCEL content type there (application/vnd.ms-excel).

It says:

You need to set the `Content-Disposition` header.

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=" + yourFileName);
```

and write your bytes directly to the response `OutputStream`.

```
File xls = new File("exported.xls"); // or whatever your file is
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(xls);
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

byte[] buffer= new byte[8192]; // use bigger if you want
int length = 0;

while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
     out.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
in.close();
out.close();
```

---

The above is relatively old. You can construct a `ResponseEntity` with [`FileSystemResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html) now. A [`ResourceHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/ResourceHttpMessageConverter.html) will then copy the bytes, as I have suggested above, for you. Spring MVC makes it simpler for you rather than having you interact with interfaces from the Servlet specification.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Post
@Path("downloadMyReport")
@Produces("application/excel")
public static Response generatemyExcelReport()throws BusinessException     {
    try {
        File file=null;
        Date reportDate=new Date() ;

        path="/home/Documents/excelReport/"
        file=getReportByName(path);

        if(file==null){
            logger.info("File is null");

        else{
                name=capitalizeFirstLater(name);

            getReportSummary(reportDate);
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(path),createExcelForReport(fileName,path));
            file=getReportByName(path);
        }   


        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(file);
        response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName2 + "\"");
        return response.build();

    }
    }catch (BusinessException e) {
        throw e;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception while generating ExcelSheetForMyReport {}",Utils.getStackTrace(e));
        throw new BusinessException("Error in downloading ExcelSheetForMyReport");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(file);
        response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName2 + "\"");
        return response.build();